# Download images from a site

Tags: windows-7, download, website, directory-listing

I want to download images from a site say, **xyz.com** which has the following directory structure:

**./a/b/c/d/pikachu.jpg**

There are thousands of images inside d directory and they are directly accessible if I type the complete address but to download all the images in bulk I am using Extreme Picture Finder which is unable to access through a starting address(It is forbidden).
My question is different form other similar questions in firstly, I can't use wget because I don't have a linux installed. Secondly, I am in favor of delegating the task somehow to Extreme Picture Finder.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

> **I can't use wget because I don't have a linux installed**

Then use the [Windows version of Wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)?

```
C:\>d:\apps\wget\wget --version
GNU Wget 1.5.3.1

Copyright (C) 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

Written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@srce.hr>.
```

---

> **I am using Windows 7.**

Me too.

```
C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Comment: Is there any way to integrate it with a bulk image downloader?

Comment: @pulp: Wget is a bulk image downloader, see `--recursive` and `--accept` as described in wget help and in the answer at http://superuser.com/a/347999/52492